# Наследование классов в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Пишу код где класс `Truck` наследует класс `Car`. Все ок, только `v2.move()` не корректно работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в терминале вместо модели машины пишет `undefined`?
Даже если `let v2 = new Truck()` поменяю на `let v2 = new Truck("Man")` все равно не дает результата.

> Машина `undefined` двигается со скоростью 80 км/час

```js
class Car {
    model;

    constructor(model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    move() {
        console.log(`Машина ${this.model} двигается со скоростью 80 км/час`);
    }
}

class Truck extends Car {
    weight;
    maxCargo;
    model;

    constructor(model, maxCargo) {
        super(model);
        this.maxCargo = maxCargo;
    }

    loadCargo(weight) {

        if (weight > 1000) {
            console.log("Этот грузовик не может перевозить более 1000кг груза");
        }
        else {
            this.weight = weight;
            console.log(`В грузовик загружено ${this.weight}кг.`);
        }
    }
}

let v1 = new Car("Mazda");
v1.move();

let v2 = new Truck();
v2.loadCargo(1500);
v2.move();
```

Comment: А для чего предназначено поле `model` в классе `Truck`?

Comment: зачем вы переопределяете в грузовике свойство `model` ?

Comment: Не нужно исправлять ошибку прямо в вопросе, это делает все ответы неактуальными, и наличие самого вопроса так же, ведь ошибки больше нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы хорошо понять что произошло, можно десахоризовать js классы в обычные функции, потому что мы не видим как именно создается класс.

Но когда мы смотрим на функцию конструктор мы четко видим последовательность действий.

В частности будет хорошо заметно что определение собственных свойств идет после вызова родительского конструктора и определения его свойств.

Я использую `Object.defineProperty` для большей наглядности того что происходит на самом деле ведь напиши я `this.model;` - ничего бы не произошло тут нет присваивания.

```js
    function Car (model) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "model", {
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: false,
          writable: true,
          value: model
        });

        this.move = function() {
            console.log(`Машина ${this.model} двигается со скоростью 80 км/час`);
        }
    }
    
    function Truck (model, maxCargo)  {
        Car.call(this, model) // вызов родительского конструктора
    
        Object.defineProperty(this, "weight", {
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: false,
          writable: true,
          value: undefined
        });
    
        Object.defineProperty(this, "maxCargo", {
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: false,
          writable: true,
          value: maxCargo
        });
        
        Object.defineProperty(this, "model", { // <= тут происходит перезапись
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: false,
          writable: true,
          value: undefined 
        });
    
        this.loadCargo = function(weight) {
            if (weight > 1000) {
                console.log("Этот грузовик не может перевозить более 1000кг груза");
            }
            else {
                this.weight = weight;
                console.log(`В грузовик загружено ${this.weight}кг.`);
            }
        }
    }
    
    let v1 = new Car("Mazda");
    v1.move();
    
    let v2 = new Truck("name");
    v2.loadCargo(1500);
    v2.move();
```

**Решение**

```js
class Car {
    model;

    constructor(model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    move() {
        console.log(`Машина ${this.model} двигается со скоростью 80 км/час`);
    }
}

class Truck extends Car {
    weight;
    maxCargo;

    constructor(model, maxCargo) {
        super(model);
        this.maxCargo = maxCargo;
    }

    loadCargo(weight) {

        if (weight > 1000) {
            console.log("Этот грузовик не может перевозить более 1000кг груза");
        }
        else {
            this.weight = weight;
            console.log(`В грузовик загружено ${this.weight}кг.`);
        }
    }
}

let v1 = new Car("Mazda");
v1.move();

let v2 = new Truck("new");
v2.loadCargo(1500);
v2.move();
```

Comment: Проблема еще не решена

Comment: приведенный выше код отвечает на вопрос **Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в терминале вместо модели машины пишет undefined?**,  а не решает, для решения нужно удалить  
 `Object.defineProperty(this, "model"...` это либо в Вашем случае `model;` из класса `Truck`

Comment: Я удалил - model из класса Truck и добавил - new Truck("name") . Код в вопросе изменен. Результат не изменился

Comment: я вижу у Вас результат `Машина new двигается со скоростью 80 км/час` в консоли в третьей строке, мы же про него говорим?

Comment: хорошо что вернули исходный код вопроса, иначе бы в вопросе не было бы смысла, вот [результат](https://i.snipboard.io/HUNnAs.jpg) который я видел

Comment: А как такое может быть. Этот же код, но у меня выдает в хроме - "Машина undefined двигается со скоростью 80 км/час" ?)

Comment: Не в курсе почему это могло произойти, на всякий случай дополнил свой ответ решением, должно работать